# How can the user logged out after 5 minutes using cookies if the user do not perform any activity in custom login page?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

how can the user logged out after 5 minutes using cookies if the user do not perform any activity in custom login page?? In Salesforce Apex Page.
here i created cookies but i dont know how to use these cookies when user is inactive and logout them.

```
Cookie firstname = new Cookie('firstname',abc.First_Name__c,null,-1,false);  
        Cookie lastname = new Cookie('lastname',abc.Last_Name__c,null,-1,false);
        //Cookie password = new Cookie('password',abc.Password__c,null,-1,false);
        Cookie email = new Cookie('email',abc.Email__c,null,-1,false);
```

Comment: downvote reason: the question title is misleading (i.e., my first assumption was that you need help with creating a custom login page), but your first line seems to be your real issue ("*how can i logged out the user after 5 minutes using cookies if the user do not perform any activity in custom login page?*")

Comment: whats the issue?

Comment: sorry i mean to say that.. when the user logged in the page.. if the user is not performing any activity. then the user will automatically logout and the cookies will be deleted.

Comment: If you edit your question title to reflect this, I can remove the downvote. That is, changing the current title **Salesforce custom login page**" to your actual issue (your very first question in you description seems to be a good candidate).

Comment: now plzz answer my question